# Converting Docker compose file and its config file to Helm chart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kompose

I have a situation where I am trying to create a Helm chart for Metricbeats, but I am running into a brick wall. My Docker Compose file two separate yaml files, one for Metricbeats and the other for the configuration of Metricbeats I need to pod to use on start up. I have used Kompose to convert the Docker compose files over, but it ignored the config yaml. I need a way to ether manually create the Helm chart or need to know how to get Kompose to convert both files into the Helm Chart.

Thank you

Here is my file structure:

```
Metricbeat
     |
     |--------------------------
docker-compose.yml              |
                              config
                                |
                                |
                          metricbeat.yml
```

When compose is run in the Metricbeat folder using the following
'kompose --file docker-compose.yml convert'

It will convert the docker compose file but not the config. Just need to know how to include this or just how to do it manually.

Comment: What have you done so far?  My loose impression has been that Kompose can do a basic conversion and give you a set of skeleton files, but you do need to for example understand how Kubernetes ConfigMaps work to get a working application.

Comment: Kompose doesn't create Charts, only raw manifests. Also, [there should already be a chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/metricbeat) (or operator) for MetricBeat. Regarding the config, see `kubectl create configmap --from-file` option. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/